# Generalise Noether's theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, noethers-theorem

[image]

I'm not sure how to generalise Noether's theorem.

For this L, I think $B\cdot\dot{x}$ is conserved so I tried to relate F and K to this and try to show that that was conserved but got no where. any ideas?